# Kinetic Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this code on internet, it is working fine on Firefox and Chrome but not working on IE.
Any body can help me. It will be much appreciated.

I have completed almost my project but stuck with this one, please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <title>drag-and-drop</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Suresh">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

        <style type="text/css">
            #left{height: 500px;padding: 10px;background-color: #ccc;float: left;width: 215px;margin-top: 10px;}
            #right{height: 500px;padding: 10px;background-color: #ccc;float: right;width: 680px;margin-top: 10px;}
        </style>
        <script src="kinetic-v5.0.1.js"></script>
        <script defer="defer"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function allowDrop(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drop(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                //alert("drop");
            }

            function dragStart(ev){
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
                //$('#'+ev.target.id).click();
                //alert("dragStart");
            }

            function dropcopy(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
                var original = document.getElementById(data);
                copyimg.src = original.src;
                ev.target.appendChild(copyimg); 
                //alert("copy");
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="site_content">
            <div id="left" ondrop="drop(event)" ondrag="allowDrop(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
                <ul id="left">
                    <li><img src="images/template-icon1.png" onclick="javascript: alert('1');" draggable="true" id="drag1" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/template-icon2.png" draggable="true" id="drag2" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/template-icon3.png" draggable="true" id="drag3" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/template-icon4.png" draggable="true" id="drag4" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="right" draggable="true" ondrop="dropcopy(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">    
            </div>

            <div id="sidebar_container">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add code source or jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am doing that

Comment: Hi Maksim, I have added this code at http://jsfiddle.net/khantanveeralam/a33Qt/3/ but it some it is not wokring on jsfiddle.net, so I have uploaded working code at http://dgbuzz.com/babyshop-explorer/test/drag-and-drop.html

Comment: Hi Friend, please help me out from this error.

Comment: Hey, I am stuck with it, can you please help me in this regards

Comment: Hey Maksim, Please help me if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `ondrag="allowDrop(event)"` to `ondragover="allowDrop(event)"` for the first DIV. 
Also keep in mind that ID's should be unique, meaning that you can use only one id per page, if you need to use it multiple times, then use classes.

Comment: @user1177785 if it solved the issue, then please mark my answer as a solution, thanks :)